# Sudo askpass not working on macOS Sierra

Tags: bash, sudo, macos

I use askpass to run commands as root. In file pass.txt I have this written:

```
#!/bin/bash 
echo mypassword
```

And then I run it like this:

```
export SUDO_ASKPASS=pass.txt ; SUDO_ASKPASS=pass.txt ; sudo -Ak true
```

Before Sierra this worked just fine, but now I get an error:

```
sudo: unknown defaults entry `askpass'
```

But askpass actually works. BTW, I get this error every time I run sudo. That's the end of shudders file after exports:

```
Defaults:ALL askpass=/Users/username/pass.txt
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the line `Defaults:ALL askpass=/Users/<username>/pass.txt` from the file /etc/sudoers. I don't know the purpose of the line – at least it seems to be malformed compared to other *Defaults* entries and reading `man sudoers`.

A proper line may be: `Path askpass = /Users/<username>/pass.txt`. I can't test this though.